# Какой самый простой способ в С++98 получения и дальнейшего вызова метода класса, тип которого текущий класс не знает?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-проектирования, проектирование, c++98

Пример:
Предположим, мы разрабатываем простой графический интерфейс:

У нас есть окна и средства управления.Чего мы хотим:

- Существует базовый класс окна реализующий скрытую от пользователя функционал работы GUI.
- От базового окна пользователь наследует конкретное окно.
- Есть класс кнопки, инстанс которой пользователь может добавить в своё окно.
- **Пользователь может передать метод своего окна в кнопку, и он будет выполняться при нажатии на эту кнопку.**

Меня интересует как достичь последнего пункта.

Подобие псевдо-кода:

```
class BaseWindow;

class Button
{
public:
    Button(BaseWindow* parent)
    {
        parent->AddButton(this);
    }

    void SetBehavior(/*Owners pointer and owner's methos*/)
    {
        /* Save Owner pointer and owner's method*/
    }

    void Clicked(/*coords*/)
    {
        if(/*coords == my coords*/)
        {
            /*Call Owner's method*/
        }
    }
};

class BaseWindow
{
    vector<Button*> Buttons;

    WindowClicked(/*coords*/)
    {
        for (std::vector<Button*>::iterator it = Buttons.begin(); it != Buttons.end(); ++it) 
        {
            it->Clicked(/*coords*/);
        }
    }

public:
    void AddButton(Button* butt)
    {
        Buttons<<butt;
    }
};

class UserWindow:public BaseWindow
{
    Button MyButton;
public:
    void FunctionForButton(Button* butt){ cout<<"Say Hello, my sweet button";}

    UserWindow():MyButton(this)
    {
        MyButton.SetBehavior(/*Put here my Function for Button and my pointer*/);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем конкретном случае вы можете решить задачу самыми базовыми средствами ядра языка, т.е. поступить так:

1. В качестве типа вызываемого метода используем тип `BehaviorPtr` - указатель на метод класса `BaseWindow`

   ```
   typedef void (BaseWindow::*BehaviorPtr)(Button *);
   ```

   Именно такой тип будет иметь параметр функции `Button::SetBehavior`. Класс `Button` будет хранить в себе как указатель `BaseWindow *parent`, так и указатель `BehaviorPtr behavior`.

   Т.е. `Button` знает только о `BaseWindow` (он и так у вас о нем знает), но ничего не знает о наследниках `BaseWindow`.
2. Вызов целевого метода из `Button` делается просто как

   ```
   (parent->*behavior)(this);
   ```
3. При инициализации `UserWindow` передаем в `Button` указатель, приведенный к этому типу при помощи `static_cast`

   ```
   MyButton.SetBehavior(static_cast<BehaviorPtr>(&UserWindow::FunctionForButton));
   ```

   так как приведение указателя-на-член-класса вверх по иерархии в С++ требует явного `static_cast`.

Все. Теперь при выполнении `(parent->*behavior)(this)` внутри кнопки будет корректно вызван метод пользовательского класса `UserWindow::FunctionForButton` (см. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3ca67866d3dc2c8)

Однако особой гибкостью такой подход обладать не будет. Вы можете добиться лучших результатов использовав стандартные функциональные объекты вместо указателей на методы. И для полной изоляции от типа "получателя" понадобится функциональность closure - `std::bind` (есть в С++98 в ограниченной форме), и функциональность type erasure - `std::function` (нет в С++98). Однако вы можете попробовать взять аналоги из Boost. Или даже реализовать type erasure в стиле `std::function` вручную.

Comment: Спасибо вам за столь развернутый ответ. Ваше решение действительно простое и легковесное.

Comment: А возможно ли теми же средствами языка добится передачи метода без использования static_cast ?(мы же добрые разработчики, мы же не будем пользователя заставлять писать такие сложные конструкции)

Comment: @Ep1c: В рамках такого подхода совсем без `static_cast` не обойтись.  Однако пользователя можно освободить от обязанности его делать на своей стороне, сделав метод `SetBehavior` кнопки шаблонным и перенеся `static_cast` туда: `template <typename T> void SetBehavior(T behavior) { this->behavior = static_cast<BehaviorPtr>(behavior); }`. (http://ideone.com/zM6rLA)

Comment: Да, более красивое для пользователя решение, только не приведет ли это к ошибке, если пользователь передаст метод чужого класса или просто адрес глобальной функции? Но в целом идею я понял .

Comment: @Ep1c: `static_cast` - это не `reinterpret_cast`. `static_cast` не позволит сделать уж совсем неправильное приведение (совсем посторонний класс или обычная функция - не пройдут). Такой `static_cast` позволяет только приводить указатели-на-члены вверх и вниз по иерархии. Разумеется, опасность тут есть - можно передать туда указатель на член `SomeOtherUserWindow` (тоже унаследовано от `BaseWindow`), которого нет в `UserWindow`. Но это уже ваша ответственность.

Comment: @Ep1c: Разумеется, можно все это напичкать дополнительными проверками правильности переданного значения и его типа. Но удобные стандартные фичи для выполнения таких проверок появились только в С++11. А в С++98 - либо Boost, либо выписывать руками.